# Completely disable Ubuntu 16.04 updates Yoga 2 11

Tags: 16.04, updates, bios, data-corruption

I was just wondering how to completely disable updates on my Yoga 2 11, which has a corrupted BIOS-- I can't fix broken updates with a reinstall anymore. I was wondering specifically if there was a way to disable the command`sudo apt-get upgrade`and the update manager as well. I don't want my laptop being updated at all, and I know I'll break my system or something if I update! Thanks for any and all input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **System Settings** go to **Software & Updates**, under **"Updates"** set **"Automatically check for updates"** to **Never**

And Disable unattended upgrades:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

Select "no" when asked "Automatically download and install stable updates?" then select "ok".

Instead of disabling `apt-get` it would be better to place a hold on packages you dont't want to get updated as shown in the answer to this question:

[How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: When I type in sudo apt-get upgrade, it asks me if I want to upgrade packages still. I'm afraid to see if it will. Will it, now?
It shows that the upgrades are there.

Comment: apt-get update only updates the list of available packages and their versions, but it does not install or upgrade any packages. As long as you have disabled updates and unattended-upgrades no packages should automatically update.

Comment: Yeah I'm not afraid of automatic updates, I'm afraid I'll stupidly type in sudo apt-get upgrade -y and upgrade everything.

Comment: Sorry I mis-read your first comment.  Yes - if you manually run `apt-get upgrade` it will install the updated packages. It shows upgrades are there (available) because `apt-get uptates` had been already run.

Comment: Well yeah, but you haven't given me a solution to keep my update-happy a** from updating/upgrading with the proper commands w/o thinking about it lol

Comment: I added to my answer so you can keep sudo privileges :D

Comment: I don't want to prevent updating of a specific package, unless you call Ubuntu and all of its components a package? I want to essentially freeze my currently-running release.

Comment: placing a hold on all packages would be one way to stop updates if you "accidentally" ran `apt-get upgrade` you could also blacklist that command. IMHO that would be as silly as disabling `rm` because you are afraid of accidentally deleting something.